# why 404 in django url?

Tags: django, django-urls

I made url for signUp page.
but it returns 404 error.
all of the other urls work well.

I don't know the reason.

1. main urls

   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('', include('mobileWeb.urls')),
       path('api/', include('api.urls')),
   ]
2. Application urls

   urlpatterns = [

   ```
   path('', views.index, name='index'),

   path('index', views.index, name='index'),
   path('addComment', views.addComment, name='addComment'),

   # users
   path('signUp', views.signUp, name='signUp'),
   path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

   path('martDetail/<int:martId>', views.martDetail, name='martDetail'),
   path('trade/<int:itemId>', views.trade, name='trade'),

   path('registerMart', views.registerMart, name='registerMart'),
   path('registerItem', views.registerItem, name='registerName'),
   path('delete', views.delete, name='delete'),
   path('deleteMart', views.deleteMart, name='deleteMart'),
   path('deleteItem', views.deleteItem, name='deleteItem'),

   path('purchaseItem', views.purchaseItem, name='purchaseItem'),
   path('selectItem', views.selectItem, name='selectItem'),
   path('addStatistics', views.addStatistics, name='addStatistics'),
   path('viewStatistics', views.viewStatistics, name='viewStatistics'),

   path('imtPosRegister', views.imtPosRegister, name='imtPosRegister'),
   path('imtPosRegisterTest', views.imtPosRegisterTest, name='imtPosRegisterTest'),
   path('imtPosSaleInfoTest', views.imtPosSaleInfoTest, name='imtPosSaleInfoTest'),
   path('imtPosSaleConfirmTest', views.imtPosSaleConfirmTest, name='imtPosSaleConfirmTest'),

   path('fsOe9ms1b', views.fsOe9ms1b, name='fsOe9ms1b'),
   path('fsOe9ms1b_ma', views.fsOe9ms1b_ma, name='fsOe9ms1b_ma'),
   path('ssOe9ms1b', views.ssOe9ms1b, name='ssOe9ms1b'),
   path('ssOe9ms1b_ma', views.ssOe9ms1b_ma, name='ssOe9ms1b_ma'),
   path('tsOe9ms1b', views.tsOe9ms1b, name='tsOe9ms1b'),
   path('tsOe9ms1b_ma', views.tsOe9ms1b_ma, name='tsOe9ms1b_ma'),
   path('writeChatting', views.writeChatting, name='writeChatting'),
   path('imageUploadChatting', views.imageUploadChatting, name='imageUploadChatting')
   ```

   ]

   if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
       urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
3. 404 in web browser
   [image]
4. 404 in console
   [image]

Comment: It is `signUp` (with uppercase `U` in your paths).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url path matching is *case-sensitive*. In your paths you wrote:

```
path('signUp', views.signUp, name='signUp'),
```

with uppercase **`U`** in `signUp`. I would however advise to use only lowercase, and rewrite this to:

```
path('signup/', views.signUp, name='signUp'),
```

The same with other paths in your `urls.py`.

Comment: offcourse I died. but when I type signUp in browser, it automatically changed to signup. and if I change the urls.py to sign'u'p, the result is same. either 404

Comment: @Jin-hyeongMa: did you add a slash `/` after the `signup` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: wow. it works well. what's the difference between slash and slashless?

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting [http:\127.0.0.1:8000\signUp](http://127.0.0.1:8000/signUp)